# MVC with JavaFX and FXML

Tags: java, design-patterns, model-view-controller, javafx, fxml

If I have a JavaFX project that uses FXML, how would I structure it to adhere to the Model-View-Controller pattern? This is what I would assume the general structure to be like:

Model - Underlying program (what the GUI is representing).
View - FXML file.
Controller - FXML controller.

The issue with this representation is that the view cannot be notified of the model's changes, as it is simply an FXML file. Should the view be the FXML controller class, and then should I have a main controller class such that the FXML controller gets information from the model, and the main controller handles the action events? In this case, how would the main controller access the JavaFX nodes?

Also, in an MVC pattern, where should the main method be? Right now, It is in my JavaFX Application class, which then does nothing for the remainder of the program. Also, should the JavaFX Application class be part of the MVC pattern, or is it only necessary to initialize the GUI?

**Summary of questions (please read the full post though):**

1. How do I structure my JavaFX project which uses FXML to adhere to the MVC pattern? Should the view be the FXML controller class, and then should I have a main controller class such that the FXML controller gets information from the model, and the main controller handles the action events?
2. In an MVC pattern, where should the main method be?
3. Should the JavaFX Application class be part of the MVC pattern, or is it only necessary to initialize the GUI?

Comment: If you try your best to decouple your GUI code with your state and logic code, you'll find your application to be quite MVC like, as separation of concerns is what MVC strives for. That may be the most pragmatic way to get to where you want to go, as there really isn't a one true MVC path to take.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187932/mvc-with-javafx?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

> How do I structure my JavaFX project which uses FXML to adhere to the
>   MVC pattern? Should the view be the FXML controller class, and then
>   should I have a main controller class such that the FXML controller
>   gets information from the model, and the main controller handles the
>   action events?

Both JavaFX and Swing push towards tight coupling between the View and the Controller, with the justification that making a generic Controller is difficult. However, MVC itself has a few interpretations so it's all a bit vague.

Given this justification on the tight coupling of the View and Controller, you have some options. I'll suggest two and maybe others can add or even disagree.

1) Accept that the View class is just a dummy for loading the FXML file, setting the `Scene` and `Stage` and so making the `FXMLController` class observe the model and update the view.

This limits the Controller to JavaFXML applications, meaning it can't easily be interchanged with Swing for instance. Although changing the View is quick and simple as long as it refers to the correct Controller and all onAction or equivalent Node attributes use the same reference.

2) Don't use the skeleton code provided. Instead make the View load the FXML file and access Nodes manually, additionally removing the `fx:controller` attribute from your FXML file and `onAction` attributes from the relevant Nodes in the FXML file.

You can then access any `Node` as needed from the FXML in the View, e.g.

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
Button example = (Button) root.lookup("#button"); // #button exists in FXMLDocument.fxml
example.setOnAction(e -> { myController.doSomething(); });
```

This gives you the advantage or specifying your own generic controller, and allows the View class to observe the model itself.

At the end of day, the most important thing is to seperate the Model from the View and Controller, since the Model is meat of the program.
[Smart Model, Thin Controller, Dumb View](http://wiki.c2.com/?ModelViewControllerhttps://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String...-)

> Where should the main method be?

Doesn't matter. However, a JavaFX application doesn't strictly need a `main` method if the JAR created is done so by the JavaFX Packager Tool, and it instead uses [`launch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.String...-) as the entry point. You could however use the `main` method as an entry point in a separate class and call [`Application.launch(MyJavaFXApplicationClass.class);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.String...-) instead.

> Should the JavaFX Application class be part of the MVC pattern, or is
>   it only necessary to initialize the GUI?

Yes, as it is part of the View. See the two methods I mentioned above.

Comment: So the Application class will have a reference to the model, observe for changes, and modify the view when necessary?

Comment: I agree with `Both JavaFX and Swing push towards tight coupling between the View and the Controller` the controller almost feels like a "support" class for the FXML file.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is not very helpful if everybody who starts with JavaFX first tries to invent his own scheme of implementing one of the variants of MVC. Instead one should pick one of the many already existing application frameworks (for JavaFX), try to understand it and then strictly follow the guidelines of this framework to build an application.
My personal favorite is [mvvmFX](https://github.com/sialcasa/mvvmFX) but of course you could also use one of the others like AfterburnerFX. Studying and using such a framework would answer many of the constantly asked questions here on SO.